# Contador de clics en wordpress para logueados

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Estuve explorando soluciones para crear un contador de clics en botones y encontré este script que publican en esta respuesta:

```
if ( is_admin() ) add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_link_click_counter', 'link_click_counter' );
function link_click_counter() {
    if ( isset( $_POST['nonce'] ) &&  isset( $_POST['post_id'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['nonce'], 'link_click_counter_' . $_POST['post_id'] ) ) {
        $count = get_post_meta( $_POST['post_id'], 'link_click_counter', true );
        update_post_meta( $_POST['post_id'], 'link_click_counter', ( $count === '' ? 1 : $count + 1 ) );
    }
    exit();
} 
add_action( 'wp_head', 'link_click_head' ); 
function link_click_head() {
global $post;
if( isset( $post->ID ) ) {
<script type="text/javascript" >
jQuery(function ($) {
    var ajax_options = {
        action: 'link_click_counter',
        nonce: '<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'link_click_counter_' . $post->ID ); ?>',
        ajaxurl: '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>',
        post_id: '<?php echo $post->ID; ?>'
    };

    $( '#countable_link' ).on( 'click', function() {
        var self = $( this );
        $.post( ajax_options.ajaxurl, ajax_options, function() {
            window.location.href = self.attr( "href" );
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

[click count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20812532/click-count-of-a-certain-link-in-wordpress-post#comment90603598_20817551)

Funciona perfectamente, solo que funciona unicamente con usuarios no logueados.

Me gustaría saber si hay posibilidad de editar ese código para que funcione al contrario: con usuarios logueados.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La acción `wp_ajax_nopriv_` se activa solo para usuarios no logeados, si quieres usarlo en usuarios logeados simplemente usa la acción `wp_ajax_`, entonces quedaria algo asi

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_link_click_counter', 'link_click_counter' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_link_click_counter', 'link_click_counter' );
```

La primera se ejecuta con usuarios logeados y la segunda con usuarios no logeados, tendrás que usar ambas acciónes si quieres que funcione en ambos estados.

Fuentes:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_nopriv_action/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_action/

Comment: Jefferzon, muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda ¡Funciona perfecto! Llevo desde anoche intentando modificar el código. Había pensado que, tal vez, tendría algo que ver con is_user_logged_in(). De verdad aprecio mucho la ayuda.

Comment: De nada @Jairo si te sirvió por favor márcalo como aceptada